# Unable to upload images in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to upload image in WordPress.

Error comes out like this:
"Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server? "
How can i change writable permission so that i can upload images properly through word press.

On some installations of WordPress, when I try to download a new theme or plugin or even update an existing plugin, I get the following message:

"To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host."

How can I remove these protection so that I can upload and delete plugins, themes, images without any FTP credentials?

Comment: The chances are that you have not set the correct permissions on your file structure. a simple test would be to open the root folder for everything to have modify permissions and then have all child folders inherit this permission of course once you have confirmed this is the problem you can then remove the everyone permission and have a look at what you need to do to allow word press to work while still keeping your system secure

Answer (score 0):

You must access the control panel of your account at your hosting company. Look for File Manager and change the permissions of folder /wp-content/plugins and wp-content/uploads to 755, include sub-folders!